# making responsive three columns woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to create columns for woocommerce, I want it to be 3 columns, column 1(step1) the billing information, column 2(step2) shipping method and payment method, column 3(step3) item details and checkout button, all in one checkout page, or is there a plugin for this?

```
<?php
/**
 * Checkout Form
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.3.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
}

wc_print_notices();

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout );

// If checkout registration is disabled and not logged in, the user cannot     checkout
if ( ! $checkout->enable_signup && ! $checkout->enable_guest_checkout && !     is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', __(     'You must be logged in to checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) );
return;
}

// filter hook for include new pages inside the payment method
$get_checkout_url = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', WC()-    >cart->get_checkout_url() ); ?>

<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( $get_checkout_url ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php if ( sizeof( $checkout->checkout_fields ) > 0 ) : ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>


    <div class="onecheckout">
<div class="step-1">Step One</div>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
        </div>
<div class="onecheckoutmid">
<div class="step-2">Step Two</div>
<h6>Delivery Method</h6>

        <div class="col-2">
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>

        </div>


</div>  
<div class="onecheckout">

<div class="step-3">Step Three</div>
<h6>Confirm Order</h6>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce provides the ability to override their checkout template files by adding a `woocommerce` directory into your WordPress theme and making any adjustments you need there.

It would require overriding several template files, but with some custom HTML and CSS, you could probably achieve the results you are looking for.

Comment: I have edite the code and end up with this, but every time I remove the review order with payment options it resulted in fatal error, i want to separate the review order and payment method here is the screenshot

http://www.zaheb.com/zhb/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/screenshot-www.zaheb_.com-2015-09-17-14-41-52.png